# CakePHP create new page

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

I want to create new page within CakePHP 2. I added two files:

> app/controllers/productsimport_controller.php

which contains:

```
<?php
class ProductsimportController extends AppController
{       
    function admin_index()
    {

    }

    function isAuthorized()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

> app/views/productsimport/admin_index.ctp

which contains:

```
<h2>Hello!</h2>
```

But I always see not this page, but previous page, where I was before. For example, if I was at `/admin/users`, I still see `/admin/users/` if I go to `/admin/productsimport`. Or sometimes `404 page`, but not what I want.

May be I forgot to add something to make it works?

Comment: What do your routes look like? Do you have `admin` setup as a route prefix?

Comment: There is only one line in routes which contains `/admin`: `Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));`.

Answer (score 0):

Your default route to the controller method is `/productsimport/*`, so to access the page you want, the url is `/productsimport/admin_index`.

What Cake does when you try to enter `/admin/productsimport` is to check for `productsImport()` method inside `AdminsController`, it does not exist so it renders the index instead.

You can change this behavior in the router

Comment: The most strange thing that there is no `AdminsController` or `AdminController`. Other parts of `/admin/*` works though their own controllers such as `ContactsController` with method `admin_index()`.

Comment: Anyway something like Router::connect('/admin/productsimport/', array('controller' => 'productsimport', 'action' => 'admin_index')); in the router should work

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be a routing one and it sounds like you do not have a route setup for `/admin/productsimport`.

If you want all actions prefixed with `admin_` in your controllers to have the [route prefix](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) `admin` then you need to enable route prefixes in `app/Config/core.php`:-

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

This will alter the routes for any controller action prefixed with `action_` like: `admin_edit` to `/admin/controller/edit`.

Otherwise you will need to set up routes for each controller action you want accessing this way. So for your particular example you would need in `app/Config/routes.php`:-

```
Router::connect('/admin/productsimport/', 
    array('controller' => 'productsimport', 'action' => 'admin_index')
);
```

Prefixing the `admin` routes would mean that this would be unnecessary.

Comment: I have this one inside `app/config/core.php`: `Configure::write('Routing.admin', 'admin');`. I think that's why `/admin/contacts` will work with method `admin_index()` inside `ContactsController`.

Comment: I added `Router::connect('/admin/productsimport/', array('controller' => 'productsimport', 'action' => 'admin_index'));` to `app/Config/routes.php` and now I have an error on `/admin/productsimport/`: `Error: ProductsimportController::admin_index() cannot be accessed directly.`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `'Routing.admin'` configuration setting, this might be specific to your app. Route prefixing should be configured with `'Routing.prefixes'` as shown in my answer. You may need to check where `'Routing.admin'` is being used to see if that is altering how `admin` routes are handled. Otherwise, you should consider using the prefixing method described.

Comment: @mrVG no problem. If this has helped you resolve your problem please up vote and/or mark it as the correct answer so that it might help anyone else having similar problems in the future. :-)